# Pulseaudio Latency Changing on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, audio-sync

Over the past few weeks I've been having some issues with audio latency on my system. To mitigate the effects of the latency, I installed `pavucontrol` and changed the latency offset to -35ms to try and counter the 35ms delay that was printed by `pactl list sinks | grep Latency*`. I noticed that if I play a video or audio with pavucontrol open, the latency stays pretty close to 0 but if I close pavucontrol the latency goes back to around 35ms.

A potential cause of the issue could be that on Kubuntu there is already a version of pavucontrol that comes with the system but you are unable to do negative latency offsets with it. I'm unsure whether the pre-installed version potentially overwrites the latency setting when the installed version is closed.

The audio output from lspci -v:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 128
        Memory at df320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Output of `pactl list sinks | grep Latency*` with pavucontrol open and Youtube video playing:

```
Latency: 180 usec, configured 40000 usec
```

Output of `pactl list sinks | grep Latency*` with pavucontrol closed and Youtube video playing:

```
Latency: 26158 usec, configured 75000 usec
```

I am using Pulseaudio 13.99.1 with the 5.4.0-37-lowlatency kernel.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.